# Изменение копии Map

Tags: java

Подскажите:

```
HashMap<String,String>data=new HashMap<>();
data.put("Имя","Вася");
data.put("Фамилия","Иванов");
HashMap<String,String>data11=data;
data.put("Имя","Петя");
System.out.println(data11.get("Имя"));
```

Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы второе `Map` сохранило значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Новая ссылка на тот же объект (то, что в вопросе):

   ```
   HashMap<String, String> data11 = data;
   ```

   ```js
   var data = {};
   data["Имя"] = "Вася";
   data["Фамилия"] = "Иванов";
   var data11 = data;
   data["Имя"] = "Петя";
   console.log(data11["Имя"]);
   ```

---

Новый объект с теми же данными (то, что Вы хотите):

```
HashMap<String, String> data11 = new HashMap<String, String>(data);
```

```js
var data = {};
data["Имя"] = "Вася";
data["Фамилия"] = "Иванов";
var data11 = Object.assign({}, data);
data["Имя"] = "Петя";
console.log(data11["Имя"]);
```